# Getting error while installing salesforce.com plugins into Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, salesforce

This is error I am getting, using windows xp and eclipse indigo

```
An error occurred while collecting items to be installed
    session context was:(profile=epp.package.java, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Collect, operand=, action=).
    Problems downloading artifact: osgi.bundle,com.salesforce.ide.api,24.0.0.201202291629.
    MD5 hash is not as expected. Expected: 7251ab037ae632a5a9835c7c07210451 and found 2d2903c04b9d1291c5486b08bed1c3f3.
    Problems downloading artifact: osgi.bundle,com.salesforce.ide.core,24.0.0.201202291629.
    MD5 hash is not as expected. Expected: 44db36699ca7fdd38917fced4e63c3b3 and found abbb32934dccfa8e090445d70db3ee00.
    Problems downloading artifact: osgi.bundle,com.salesforce.ide.documentation,24.0.0.201202291629.
    MD5 hash is not as expected. Expected: 6d87eb2e76e7e19f7b709682e5272dfc and found b53354a2eed289832ef9d4f81fa4511d.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Force.com IDE isn't supported in Eclipse Indigo (3.7), so I wouldn't bother contacting support about it. You'll have to use an earlier version of Eclipse like Helios (3.6/3.5/3.4 are supported).  Or just install the [standalone Force.com IDE](http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/Force.com_IDE_Installation).

Answer (score 0):

The messages seem pretty clear: the MD5 hash of the plugins you're trying to install don't match what they are supposed to be. It suggest that salesforce.com has a problem in their p2 repository - you should contact them about it through whatever support channel they provide.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend Eclipse Helios (3.6) with force.com plugin